# Is there a way to stop prettier from breaking function arguments into new lines

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

i have this function

what i want / desired output :

```
    function _approve( address owner, address spender, uint256 amount ) internal virtual {

        require(owner != address(0), 'ERC20: approve from the zero address');
        require(spender != address(0), 'ERC20: approve to the zero address');

        _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
    }
```

but pretier keep breaking the function arguments and i could not fiind a way to stop it from doing that

what i got :

```
    function _approve(
        address owner,
        address spender,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal virtual {
        require(owner != address(0), 'ERC20: approve from the zero address');
        require(spender != address(0), 'ERC20: approve to the zero address');

        _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
    }
```

i tried  "printWidth": 500 but to no effect and i know that i can use
`// prettier-ignore`
to skip that line but is there a way to make it applicable for all code

Comment: maybe just change your `max_line_length` setting? https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html. Does that answer your question? If not, what am I missing?